# List of the first item in a sublist

Tags: python

I want a list that displays the first element of the sublists I input.

```
def firstelements(w):
    return [item[0] for item in w]
```

Which works, but when I try doing

```
firstelements([[10,10],[3,5],[]])
```

there's an error because of the `[]`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a condition to your list comprehension so that empty lists are skipped.

```
def firstelements(w):
    return [item[0] for item in w if item != []]
```

If you wish to represent that empty list with *something* but don't want an error you might use a conditional expression in your list comprehension.

```
def firstelements(w):
    return [item[0] if item != [] else None for item in w]
```

```
>>> firstelements([[10,10],[3,5],[]])
[10, 3, None]
```

Comment: can just be `if item`

Comment: True. I opted to be more explicit in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition to check if the item has data.

```
def firstelements(w):
    return [item[0] for item in w if item]
```

Below are 3 more ways you can write it that don't require a condition. `filter` strips out `None`/"Empty" values.

```
def firstelements(w):
    return list(zip(*filter(None, w)))[0]
```

```
def firstelements(w):
    return [item[0] for item in filter(None, w)]
```

```
def firstelements(w):
    return [i for (i,*_) in filter(None, w)]
```